# How to incorporate SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() into existing web application

Tags: mysql

I just read about mysql's SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() which helps you get the total result size of a previously executed query by dropping the LIMIT conditions.  Now i want to use this feature in an existing web application.

I have a few approaches in mind, but I'm not sure which is best:

1) Does PHP already have functions that use the FOUND_ROWS() feature?  I'm using php 5 with mysqli and mysql 5 with innodb storage engine.

2) The application I'm building already has it's own data access object that wraps the mysqli library.  It is responsible for generating frequently used CRUD queries.  Should I edit this object to include the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS on all SELECT queries?  What complications might exist?

Any other ideas/feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Does PHP already have functions that use the `FOUND_ROWS()` feature? I'm using php 5 with mysqli and mysql 5 with innodb storage engine.

I thought [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) does it, but after a little browsing I think I might be wrong.

**UPDATE:** Yes, I'm wrong :)

> 2) The application I'm building already has it's own data access object that wraps the mysqli library. It is responsible for generating commonly used `CRUD` queries. Should I edit this object to include the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` on all `SELECT` queries? What complications might exist?

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` will try to calculate number of rows that would be returned be there no `LIMIT` clause in your query.

This will utilize metadata in one and only one case:

1. When your table uses `MyISAM` engine, **AND**

   - When your query has no `WHERE` clause.

In other cases `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` will count the rows one by one, impacting performance.

Don't append it to each and every query.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Couldn't find anything regarding MyISAM (or InnoDB) + `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, are you sure that InnoDB counts rows one by one?

Answer (score 1):

1.) No, php doesn't have a function like this.

2.) I think it's better to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS only when you really need it.